# Popping from stack ,program runs infinite loop

Tags: c, stack

The program here runs infinite loop in ***while*** loop inspite it is restricted to stop at stack being empty.

```
void printPostorder(TreeNode *pn)
{
TreeNode* temp=pn;
TreeNode* prev=NULL;
if(!pn)
  return;
push(temp);
while(stack_notempty())
{
    temp=topnode();
    if(prev==NULL||prev->left==temp||prev->right==temp)
    {
        if(temp->left)
            push(temp->left);
        if(temp->right)
            push(temp->right);
        if(temp->right==NULL&&temp->left==NULL)
        {
            printf("%d,",temp->data);
            pop();
        }
    }
    if(prev==temp->left)
    {
        if(temp->right)
            push(temp->right);
        else
        {
            printf("%d,",temp->data);
            pop();
        }
    }
    if(prev==temp->right)
    {
        printf("%d,",temp->data);
        pop();
    }
    prev=temp;
}

}
```

The stack operations are:

```
int stack_notempty()
{
if(s.top==-1||s.top<-1)
    {
    return 0;
    }
else 
    return 1;

}
```

The above function returns zero on stack being empty thus ending the loop

```
void push (TreeNode* node)
{

if (s.top == (MAXSIZE - 1))
{
    printf ("Stack is Full\n");
    return;
}
else
{
    s.top = s.top + 1;
    s.stk[s.top] = node;
}
return;
}
TreeNode* pop ()
{
TreeNode* node;

    node = s.stk[s.top];
    s.top = s.top - 1;

return(node);
}

TreeNode* topnode()
{
TreeNode* tnod;
tnod = pop();
push(tnod);
return tnod;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int stack_notempty()
{
if(s.top==-1||s.top<-1)
    {
    return 0;
    }

}
```

Not all branches here return a value. Therefore the behavior of any code that depends on this value is undefined. You must *always* return a value if the function is declared to return something.

---

Side note, but it's a bit confusing to name a predicate as a negative. Imagine code like this:

```
if(!stack_notempty())
```

Did you do a double take? Imagine reading it in the distant future when you are debugging this.

Comment: @prithviparre - Then you have another logical error. Somewhere in your loop, you get a node for which `pop` is never called.